# Sort in order from greatest to least using pandas group by

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-analysis

Trying to sort from greatest to least of the sales of a company that also rearranges the names of the companies based on the index of the sales in the list.

I cannot figure out what to try as I am stuck.

```
df=df.groupby(df['Distributor'])['Tickets Sold'].sum() 
df1=df[df.div(df.sum()).lt(0.01)] df2=df.drop(df1.index) 
yourdf=pd.concat([df2,pd.Series(df1.sum(),index=['Others'])])
print(yourdf)
```

Instead of this.

```
20th Century Fox 141367982   
Focus Features 18799261 
Lionsgate 75834308 
Paramount Pictures 86302817 
STX Entertainment 22606674 
Sony Pictures 102746480 
Universal 159556790 
Walt Disney 315655340 
Warner Bros. 216426845 
Others 74618013
```

I need this.

```
Walt Disney 315655340 
Warner Bros. 216426845 
Universal 159556790 
20th Century Fox 141367982 
Sony Pictures 102746480 
Paramount Pictures 86302817 
Lionsgate 75834308
Others 74618013 
STX Entertainment 22606674 
Focus Features 18799261
```

Answer (score 0):

This solves your problem!

```
df=df.groupby(df['Distributor'])['Tickets Sold'].sum()
df1=df[df.div(df.sum()).lt(0.01)]
df2=df.drop(df1.index)
yourdf=pd.concat([df2,pd.Series(df1.sum(),index=['Others'])])

yourdf = yourdf.sort_values(ascending=False)
print(yourdf)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sort_values() method

```
   df.sort_values(by=['ColName'], ascending=False)
```

Comment: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'by'

Comment: Check out the documentation for the method here. Maybe you are using an earlier version of pandas? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html